# How to retrive the href value along with the text using DOM?

Tags: php, dom

I have a HTML snipet available here
https://jsfiddle.net/yogusmilu/y9zom7hf/

I am trying to get the value mentioned in the image below. The same HTML data is available on fiddle

[image]

This code helps me to strip the text inside the `<li>` but I need the href value too.

```
<?php

function curl_download( $url ) {
header("Content-Type:text/plain");
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return (object)array(
    'response'  =>  $output,
    'info'      =>  $info
);
} 
$output = curl_download( 'https://www.jkpsc.nic.in' );

if( $output->info['http_code']==200 ){

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    $dom=new DOMDocument;

    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
   // $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->substituteEntities=true;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->formatOutput=true;

    $dom->loadHTML( $output->response );

    libxml_clear_errors();

    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
   $col=$xp->query('//li[@style="display: none"]');

    if( !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $node )echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
} else {
    echo '<pre>',print_r($output->info,true),'</div>';
}
?>
```

The result of this is

```
24/01/2023 Important notice for the candidates who had appeared in the written examination for various posts in Skill Development Department, in response to Notification No.06-PSC (DR-P) of 2022 dated 24.01.2022. 22/01/2023 Written Test for the post of ALR/DLO -2022,  Provisional Answer Key   20/01/2023 Result of JK Combined Competitive (Mains) Examination 2021, Deployment of candidates for Medical Examination thereof  20/01/2023 Conduct of the Written Test Assistant Legal Remembrancer/District Litigation Officer in the Department of Law, Justice and Parliamentary Affairs - Appointment of Observers thereof  19/01/2023 Important Notice regarding the conduct of Written Examination of Assistant Legal Remembrancer/District Litigation Officer, 2022 19/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the posts of Lecturer Medical Physics in State Cancer Institute (SCI) at Super Specialty Hospital (GMC Jammu) in Health and Medical Education Department. 17/01/2023 JK Combined Competitive (Main) Examination, 2021- Result of Rechecking reg
 17/01/2023 Filling up of the posts of Medical Officer (Backlog) in Health and Medical Education Department. 17/01/2023 Interview schedule for the posts of Lecturer Paediatrics Surgery, Super Specialty Hospital (GMC-Jammu/Srinagar) in Health and Medical Education Department - Addendum to Notice dated 16.01.2023 thereof. 16/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the posts of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Shalya (Surgery) in Govt. Ayurvedic Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 16/01/2023 Interview schedule for the posts of Lecturer Paediatric Surgery, Super Specialty Hospital (GMC-Jammu/Srinagar) in Health and Medical Education Department. 16/01/2023 Accounts Clerk Course/SAC Part-I/SAC Part-II Departmental Examination, 2023 - Extension of date for filling of online application form thereof.  12/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Panchkarma in Govt. Ayurvedic Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 12/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Rachna Shariri (Anatomy) in Govt. Ayurvedic Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 12/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Prasuti Evam Striroga (Gynecology and Obsts) in Govt. Ayurvedic Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 10/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Kaumarbharitya (Paediatrics) in Govt. Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 10/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Kayachiktsa (Medicine) in Govt. Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 10/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Roga Nidan and Vikriti Vigyana (Pathology) in Govt. Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor in Health and Medical Education Department. 06/01/2023 Filling up of the posts of AE Mechanical in PW Department - Result of Written Test reg 06/01/2023 Rejection of candidature for the post of Deputy Medical Superintendent in Government Ayurvedic Medical College cum Hospital, Akhnoor, Jammu in HME 06/01/2023 Conduct of written Tests for the posts of AE Mechanical - Final Answer Key thereof 05/01/2023 Rejection of Candidature for the post of Deputy Medical Superintendent in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital Gnaderbal in HME Department 04/01/2023 Filling of Gazetted vacancies in Super Specialty Hospitals, Jammu/Srinagar, GMC, Srinagar, Jammu, Anantnag, Baramulla, Doda, Kathua, Rajouri, Indra Gandhi Dental College, Jammu and GDC, Srinagar. 03/01/2023 Filling up of Gazetted posts in Forest, Ecology and Environment Department - Edit window regarding  31/12/2022 Filling up of Gazetted vacancies in Super Speciality Hospitals, GMC Jammu, Srinagar -GMC Srinagar, Jammu, Anantnag, Baramulla, Doda Kathua, and Rajouri  30/12/2022 Date sheet for J and K Combined Competitive (Main) Examination, 2022. Filling up of the posts of District Sericulture Officer in Agriculture Production and Farmers Welfare Department. 30/12/2022 Filling up of the posts of District Sericulture Officer in Agriculture Production and Farmers Welfare Department. 30/12/2022 Filling up of Gazetted vacancies in GMC Handwara and GMC Udhampur 30/12/2022 Filling up of the posts of District Sericulture Officer in Agriculture Production and Farmers Welfare Department. 28/12/2022 Statistical Assistant Course Departmental Examination, 2022 - Rejection of candidature thereof. 27/12/2022 Online applications are invited from the eligible candidates desirous of appearing in the Accounts Clerk Course/SAC Part-I/SAC Part-II Departmental Examination.  27/12/2022 Filling up of posts of Assistant engineer (Civil) in Jal Shakti Department. 24/12/2022 Written Test for the post of Assistant Engineer (Mechanical), 2022 - Provisional Answer Key. 23/12/2022 Secretariat Assistant Course/Foundation Course Departmental Examination, Session, 2022 - Declaration of result thereof. 22/12/2022 Notification regarding filling up of the post of Assistant Commissioner Food Safety and Assistant Controller Drugs, J and K Drugs and Food Control Organisation in Health and Medical Education Department. 20/12/2022 Deficiency notice of Junior Statistical Assistant/Statistical Assistant and Statistical Officer Course Departmental Examination, 2022. 20/12/2022 Filling up of the posts of Veterinary Assistant Surgeons in the Animal Husbandry Department. 20/12/2022 JK Combined Competitive (Main) Examination, 2021, Interview of the candidate on the basis of Honble Court Orders 19/12/2022 Conduct of written Tests for the posts of Scientific Officers in FSL, J and K Home Department - Final Answer Key thereof. 19/12/2022 Filling up of  the posts of Scientific Officers in FSL, JK Home Department - Result of Written Test reg 19/12/2022 Conduct of written Test for filling up of Gazetted vacancies of Department of Skill Development - Final Answer Key thereof 19/12/2022 Filling up of  the Gazetted vacancies (various posts) Department of Skill Development - Result of Written Test reg 19/12/2022 Notice regarding filling up of the posts of Assistant Legal Remembrancer/District Litigation Officer in the Department of Law, Justice and Parliamentary Affairs. 19/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/AP Munafeul-Aza in Govt. in Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department.  15/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor AMRAZE-JILID-WA-TAZEENIYAT in Government Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department.
 15/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Ilmul Saidla (Pharmacy) in Government Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 14/12/2022 JK Combined Competiitve (Main) Examination, 2021, Interview of the candidates on the basis of Honble Court Orders 14/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Assistant Professor Munafeul-Aza (Physiology) in Government Unani Medical College cum Hospital in Health and Medical Education Department. 13/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor ILAJ BIT TADBEER (REGIMENTAL THERAPY)  in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 12/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Mahiyat Ul Amraz (Pathology) in Govt. Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Assistant Professor Moalajat (Medicine) in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Assistant Professor Tahiffuzi-wa-Samjai-Tib (Social and Preventive Medicines) in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor, Ilmul
Saidla (Pharmacy) Government in Unani Medical College cum Hospital,
Ganderbal,in Health &amp; Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Paediatric Surgery, Super Specialty Hospital, GMC Srinagar in Health and Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Paediatric Surgery, Super Specialty Hospital, GMC Jammu in Health and Medical Education Department. 09/12/2022 Rejection of the candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant
Professor, Kuliyat (Basic Principles) in Government Unani Medical
College cum Hospital, Gaerbal in Health &amp; Medical Education
Department. 08/12/2022 Rejection of the candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Niswan-wa-Qabalat in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 08/12/2022 Rejection of the candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor Ain-Uzn-Halaq-Wa-Asnan in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 08/12/2022 Rejection of the candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor IImul Advia in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 08/12/2022 Rejection of the candidature for the post of Lecturer/Assistant Professor IImul Atfal in Govt. Unani Medical College cum Hospital, Ganderbal in Health and Medical Education Department. 07/12/2022 Notice regarding rejection of representations filed by candidates for filing up of Application Forms through offline mode. 05/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Prosthodontics including Dental Material in Indra Gandhi Govt. Dental College, Jammu in Health and Medical Education Department. 02/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Oral and Dental Pathology in IGDC, Jammu  in HME 02/12/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Bio-Chemistry in State Cancer Institute (SCI) at Super Specialty Hospital, GMC Jammu. 01/12/2022 Consideration of application of Mr. Bilal Ahmad Seh for the post of Assistant Professor (Fine Arts), in compliance to Honble High Court dated 12.08.2022 passed in WP(C) No.1641/2022. 01/12/2022 Conduct of Prosecuting Officer (Preliminary) Examination, 2022 and Assistant Legal Remembrancer/District Litigation Officer Written Examination, 2022
 30/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Oral Surgery in Government Dental College, Srinagar in Health and Medical Education Department. 30/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Prosthodontics including Dental Material in Govt. Dental College, Srinagar in Health and Medical Education Department. 30/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Periodontia in Government Dental College, Srinagar in Health and Medical Education Department. 30/11/2022 Filling of Gazetted posts in Super Specialty, Jammu/Srinagar, Govt. Medical College, Srinagar, Jammu, Anantnag, Baramulla, Doda, Kathua, Indra Gandhi Dental College, Jammu and Govt Dental College, Srinagar - withdrawal of posts thereof. 30/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Conservative/Operative Dentistry in Government Dental College, Srinagar in Health and Medical Education Department. 30/11/2022 Filling of gazetted posts in Forest, Ecology and Environment Department -  extension of date thereof. 29/11/2022 Consideration order in compliance to Honble CAT order dated 28.10.2021 passed in OA No.1616/2021 titled Ruchika Kumari Vs UT of J and K and others. 28/11/2022 Notice regarding conduct of Written Test for the posts of Assistant Engineer (Mechanical) in Public Works (R and B) Department. 25/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Conservative Dentistry and Operative Dentistry in Indra Gandhi Government Dental College, Jammu. 25/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Public Health Dentistry in Indra Gandhi Government Dental College, Jammu. 24/11/2022 Conduct of written Test for filling up of Gazetted vacancies of Department of Skill Development - Provisional Answer Key theerof.  23/11/2022 Provisional selection List for the posts of Lecturer Radiology, in Institute of Mental Health and Neuro Sciences (IMHANS) (GMC-Srinagar), in Health and Medical Education Department. 23/11/2022 Annexure to Notification No. 18-PSC (DR-S) of 2022 dated 23.11.2022. 23/11/2022 Annexure to Notification No. 20-PSC (DR-s) of 2022 dated 23.11.2022. 23/11/2022 Provisional selection List for the posts of Lecturer Psychiatry in Institute of Mental Health and Neuro Sciences (IMHANS) (GMC-Srinagar) in Health and Medical Education Department. 23/11/2022 Provisional selection List for the posts of Lecturer Anaesthesia in Institute of Mental Health &amp; Neuro Sciences (IMHANS) (GMC-Srinagar) in Health and Medical Education Department. 23/11/2022 Provisional selection List for the posts of Lecturer Radio-diagnosis (GMC-Jammu), in State Cancer Institute (SCI), at Super Specialty Hospital, in Health and Medical Education Department 23/11/2022 Annexure to Notification No. 19-PSC (DR-s) of 2022 dated 23.11.2022. 22/11/2022 Conduct of written Tests for the posts of Scientific Officers in FSL, J and K Home Department - Provisional Answer Key thereof. 21/11/2022 Annexure-B to Notification No. PSC/Exam/2022/33 dated 19.11.2022 - Detailed Application Form for KAS -2021  21/11/2022 J and K Combined Competitive (Main) Examination, 2021 - Court cases regarding. 21/11/2022 Interview schedule for the candidates who have qualified J and K Combined Competitive (Main) Examination, 2021. 19/11/2022 JK Combined Competitive (Mains) Examination 2021 - Result thereof 17/11/2022 Notice regarding the conduct of Serology Paper for the post of Scientific Officer Biology/Serology in Home (FSL) Department. 16/11/2022 Syllabus for the post of Soil Conservation Assistant and Photo Interpreter Annexure C to Notification No.25-PSC (DR-P) of 2022 16/11/2022 Interview schedule of Associate Professors for the post of Principal in different Govt Degree Colleges 15/11/2022 In continuation interview schedule of Associate Professors for the post of Principal in different Govt Degree Colleges 10/11/2022 Rejection notice for the post of Assistant Professor Radiation Oncology in SCI Super Specialty Hospital GMC Jammu 09/11/2022 Revised Interview schedule of Assistant Professors for the post of Principal in different Govt Degree Colleges to be held at JKPSC office Jammu  07/11/2022 Filling up of the posts of Prosecuting Officer in J and K Home Department Extension in last date thereof 03/11/2022 Online applications are invited for the Gazetted Posts in Forest Ecology and Environment Department 03/11/2022 Rejection of candidature for the post of Lecturer Clinical Psychologist in SCI at Super Specialty Hospital GMC Jammu
```

,

Can someone please help how to fetch the href value also?

Answer (score 0):

you can do with js

```
let anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
anchorElements .forEach(function(link){
    let href = link.getAttribute("href");
    let innerText = link.innerText;
    console.log("Href: " + href + "Text:" + innerText );
});
```

This will give you both href and innertext data.

Comment: How to integerate this in my PHP code  ?